# WPF binding from code-behind to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to view the coordinates of a mouse click on a WPF screen with no luck.  I have a rudimentary grid layout with a Textblock that will display these coordinates.  I have bound values from the xaml to a code-behind before but am not sure if this direction is possible.  My xaml is as follows

```
<Window x:Class="MouseUpExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Name="MyWindow">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GetMouseCoordinates}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and my code-behind is as follows

```
    using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MouseUpExample

{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Point currentPoint = new Point();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string GetMouseCoordinates(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
            return currentPoint.ToString();
        }
        return "error";
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should bind the property not the method

Comment: By binding the property, would I be binding MouseButtonState.Pressed?

Comment: The String where you get the values

Answer (score 3):

You've got multiple problems here.

Problem #1 is that you can't bind to a method. It needs to be a property and preferably either a `DependencyProperty` or one that takes part in the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Problem #2 is that binding works with the DataContext by default, but you're not setting the `DataContext` of your `TextBlock`, either explicitly or implicitly.

Problem #3 is that this doesn't really make sense. Is `GetMouseCoordinates` an event handler for something? You probably would want to split out the event handler and the property.

I'd suggest that you [go read up on DataBinding in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and then give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to bind you'd have to set the DataContext to a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and bind to its properties. As you don't have it defined I'd set that text directly in the view.

```
<Window x:Class="MouseUpExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    Name="MyWindow" MouseDown="MainWindow_OnMouseDown">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBlock.Text = e.GetPosition(this).ToString();
}
```